# Why shift the result of subtracting vectors?

Tags: arithmetic, vectors

Why do we shift the resulting vector after subtracting any two vectors **a** and **b**?

I learned that when you *add* any two vectors **a** and **b**, the sum vector looks like the one that can be seen in the picture below (result could be found by adding the respective x and y coordinates of the two vectors, or any visual/geometric methods, such as the triangle or parallelogram methods).

[image]

Now since the *subtraction* of vector **b** from **a** can be defined as the addition of the negative (reversed) version of vector **b** (or *a + (-b)*), shouldn't the result be something like this:

[image]

Here vector **v** is subtracted from vector **u**, or u + (-v).

Instead, my book and the website that explains this concept say that the resulting vector can simply be *shifted* or translated so that a complete "triangle" of sorts is formed like so:

[image]

Note that the vector (u - v) has been shifted to the right now.

While I understand that the direction and magnitude of the vector haven't changed as a result of the shifting, I don't understand why we can just change it's origin or position in the space. I'm assuming all these vectors are defined by a coordinate pair, meaning that their origin is implicitly defined to be the origin (0, 0), right? The addition and subtraction of any two vectors originating from (0, 0) would therefore also start at (0, 0,) as is the case when adding two vectors. However shifting the resulting vector of subtracting two vectors results in a vector that has two non-"origin" points. What am I understanding wrongly here? I'd appreciate any clarification!

So, 1) what reasons would one have to shift such a vector and 2) why is it not mathematically incorrect to do so?

Comment: Your second diagram is how I would visualize vector subtraction myself. For your third diagram, the resultant of the $\color{blue}{\mathbf v}$ and $\color{#E19C24}{\mathbf u -\mathbf v}$ is of course $\color{blue}{\mathbf v}+\left(\color{#E19C24}{\mathbf u -\mathbf v}\right)=\color{red}{\mathbf u}$, and that is how the diagram reads to me.

Comment: You may be confusing two concepts of vectors as well: one as a displacement, and one as a position i.e. displacement *from a fixed origin*. Unless you are explicitly working with the latter, the former is appropriate and justifies the approach used in your textbook.

Comment: Yeah that definitely caused/added to my confusion. I was actually working with a physics book and the example *combined* position vectors (in this case the displacement of a moving object from an arbitrary fixed point or "origin" at a certain point in time) with displacement vectors (the distance and direction from one position to the next) which were found by subtracting any two position vectors (the object at two different locations/points in time).

Comment: I thought that because the position vectors originate from this origin or arbitrary fixed point, that the displacement vectors would have to as well, which would visually just result in a messy bundle of vectors. Instead the book of course placed these displacement vectors at the tips of the position vectors, creating an image of the "path" that the object approximately traveled.

Comment: Here an image of what I was describing: http://i.imgur.com/KEefG9H.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to (2): 
Informally, a vector is defined by its length and its orientation, and nothing else. You can consider the vector to be located at any position that's convenient, and move it however you like — any translated version of a vector is considered to be the same vector because it retains the same length and orientation.

Answer to (1): Thinking visually helps tremendously when doing math. You might translate vectors so that the picture of a *sum of two vectors* or a *difference of two vectors* makes intuitive geometric sense. To me, the second picture of vector subtraction is easier to remember and imagine.

Comment: Thinking visually is detrimental in the long run

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe I understand this now, I think I was too focused on thinking vectors were defined by two *points*, which I guess would make them a segment, and not a vector which is only supposed to define a magnitude/length and orientation/angle.

Comment: Thinking visually is a demonstrably helpful technique to develop initial understanding. It requires adequate transition into abstraction, a lack of which is the problem, not the use of visually-aided understanding in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Remember we represent vectors as arrows, but they are not as such. Vectors are a way to represent a displacement!
For this reason every two vectors with same magnitude and direction are indistinguishable for the majority of the mathematicians and physicists I guess.
Whether you apply this vector to the origin or you shift it, the vector is the same.

Maybe it is more clear, for someone who's learning about vectors, to use your diagram, however the pro of using the other one is that in that way, you can use the OTHER diagonal of the same parallelogram to find the difference, and this is easier to remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't sure which of the two answers to accept, since they are almost identical, so I just went with the one posted earlier, I still upvoted you though, thanks again.

Comment: Don't worry, he posted first so he deserves it maybe!