# Why do the (nonzero) vectors $x,y, x-y$ form a triangle? (can assume $\mathbb{R}^2$)

Tags: vectors, visualization

Let $x,y$ be any two nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are not scalar multiplies of eachother (i.e. are not linearly dependent), and $x-y$ be their difference.

I am wondering why these three vectors, $x,y,x-y$, always form a triangle (subject to repositioning).

I get that it is likely just from the definition of the difference between two vectors, but I don't see how it follows from the definition

I am looking more for a formal proof than intuition.

Edit: By "Form a triangle" I mean that if you draw $x$ and $y$ as starting at the same point, and draw $x-y$ as starting at the tip of $y$, the resulting picture will be a triangle.

For an example see the third picture [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841976/344247)

I.e., why is the length of $x-y$ sufficient so that $x-y$, when placed at the tip of $y$, goes from the tip of $x$ to the tip of $y$ (when $x$ and $y$ originate at the same point). How do we know (formally) that there is no "gap"?

Comment: Which three vectors?  Aren't they all colinear (or $\bf{0}$)?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Edited to make more clear

Comment: What if $x=y=0$?

Comment: @amsmath Assume they are all nonzero. and that they are not parallel

Comment: What do you get when you add $x-y$ to $y$? What does this look like when you place these vectors head-to-tail?

Comment: @amd but how do you know that the length of $x-y$ is the correct length so that there is no gap

Comment: It’s a direct consequence of the definition of vector addition and of the formula distance between two points. Expand into coordinates and work through the algebra to convince yourself that it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for three linearly independent vectors $A,B,C $to form a triangle we need to have $A+B+C=0$

Thus $A,B,-A-B$ form a triangle if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

The result could be easily generalized to a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the vector $x-y$ at the end of $y$ the resulting displacement is $y+(x-y)=x$  This is why they form a triangle.

Comment: ??? Of course they form a triangle...

Comment: If you reposition $x-y$ so that it begins at the tip of $y$ then they would form a triangle

Comment: @user106860 Maybe you should define what you mean by "form a triangle". I understand it as "the points form a triangle". Then in the example above no repositioning is needed. They form a triangle.

Comment: I think the phrasing of the question means to treat each vector as a line segment from the origin and then do a translation of the line segment represented by $x-y$ such that the three line segments form the edges of a triangle.

Comment: @JessicaK Yes, OP edited his question accordingly.

Comment: Now that OP has clarified form a triangle I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes a picture:

[image]

By the paralellogram rule for vector addition, $\overrightarrow{OD}$ is $x-y$. It should be clear that $\triangle{AOB} \cong \triangle{OAD}$ and that $AB \parallel OD$ so $x-y$ indeed “fills the gap.”